# Check dependencies and generate download script before installing by dpkg

Tags: command-line, package-management, dpkg

I used to install packages with `dpkg -i *.deb` command for off-line installation. Because all deb files are in one folder.

I want to **avoid dependency error** and stop installing packages as **broken**.

> **Ultimately my aim is to check dependencies and generate download script (if all dependencies are not satisfied) for only those package
>   which is missing in mentioned folder. so-that I can first download missing packages and Then confidently 
>   install package by `dpkg -i *.deb`**

`apt-cache showpkg $(find -iname '*.deb' -exec dpkg --info '{}' \; | awk '/Package:/ {print $2}')` shows dependencies but long list and not helpful to check **whethter it is satisfied (exist) in mentioned folder** or not. Also `dpkg -I *.deb` errors following:

```
   dpkg-deb: 'cabextract_1.4-4_i386.deb' contains no control component 'chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_34.0.1847.116-0ubuntu2_i386.deb'
   dpkg-deb: 'cabextract_1.4-4_i386.deb' contains no control component 'flashplugin-installer_11.2.202.350ubuntu1_i386.deb'
..
..
so on for each deb
```

Hence, That commands are not useful for me.

Further Clarification:

1. First check all deb dependencies in my folder.
2. according to package already installed, check this deb's are able to installed without dependency error or not.
3. if yes then execute `dpkg -i *.deb`
4. else list missing package **which not fond installed or in mentioned folder**

Thanks.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you expect to get a complete script from us? Why don't you use the results and write it yourself?

Comment: This question is no longer supported from my side because now I am using **Local repository method** to install debs offline (as APT is standard method)

Answer (score 4):

You can always try a [dry run](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg.1.html) before the install,

```
dpkg --dry-run -i *.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of the packages dependencies with:

```
find *deb -exec dpkg -f {} Depends \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try one of these

```
 dpkg -I package
 apt-cache rdepends package.deb
 apt-cache showpkg package-name
```

this one is a combination of steps incase it's just a .deb file

```
 ar -x <package-name>.deb
 tar -xzf control.tar.gz
 grep Depends control
```

or

```
 apt-cache depends package-name
```

for example

```
 apt-cache depends mplayer
```

but i think the last option is what might serve you best